# How to reindex child documents?

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to change number of primary shards in ElasticSearch. My index consists of 2 types of documents: parents and childs. I've used Reindex API to copy all parent documents to new index with different number of shards. I can't reindex child documents because they requieres parents. How to reindex child documents?

Comment: Are you seeing a specific error message (can you post if so), and can you also post the curl you're using too. The docs note that:  By default if _reindex sees a document with routing then the routing is preserved unless it’s changed by the script - so there shouldn't be an issue for docs with routing / parent information set. Or are you not using real child / parent relationships in ES, and have rolled your own?

Comment: did you try reindexing without mentioning the type?

Comment: I've solved my problem without using reindexing. I've generated those data again. However I still don't know how to do that in ES. When I'm using Reindex API to childs, for each document I have to know his parent. I don't know how pass parent_id in Reindex API. This parameter is different for each document.